# The probability distribution of two words in a file using java 8

Tags: java-8, lucene, stanford-nlp, probability-distribution

I need the number of lines that contain two words. For this purpose I have written the following code:
The input file contains `1000 lines` and about `4,000 words`, and it takes about 4 hours.
Is there a library in `Java` that can do it faster?
Can I implement this code using `Appache Lucene` or `Stanford Core NLP` to achieve less run time?

```
ArrayList<String> reviews = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String,Double> pij = new HashMap<String,Double>();

BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr = null;
try 
    {
        fr = new FileReader("src/reviews-preprocessing.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
            for(String term : line.split(" "))
                {
                    if(!terms.contains(term))
                        terms.add(term);
                }
                reviews.add(line);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();} 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}    
    }
long Count = reviews.size();
for(String term_i : terms)
    {
        for(String term_j : terms)
            {
                if(!term_i.equals(term_j))
                {
                    double p = (double) reviews.parallelStream().filter(s -> s.contains(term_i) && s.contains(term_j)).count();
                    String key = String.format("%s_%s", term_i,term_j);
                    pij.put(key, p/Count);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Libraries are no magic. You code isn’t slow because you’re not using a library, it’s slow because you’re using two nested loops containing another stream operation. That is, `term.size()`×`term.size()`×`reviews.size()` operations.

Comment: That's right, but this is inevitable. So I thought it might be possible to use a faster method instead of using the ParllelStream. @Holger

Comment: It’s not inevitable. That’s the art of developing algorithms. It’s the reason why we know so many different sorting algorithms; there are many different ways to solve the same task and you can never assume that there can’t be a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first loop getting the distinct words relies on `ArrayList.contains`, which has a linear time complexity, instead of using a `Set`. So if we assume *nd* distinct words, it already has a time complexity of “*number of lines*”×*nd*.

Then, you are creating *nd*×*nd* word combinations and probing all 1,000 lines for the presence of these combination. In other words, if we only assume 100 distinct words, you are performing 1,000×100 + 100×100×1,000 = 10,100,000 operations, if we assume 500 distinct words, we’re talking about 250,500,000 already.

Instead, you should just create the combinations actually existing in a line and collect them into the map. This will only process those combinations actually existing and you may improve this by only checking either of each “a_b”/“b_a” combination, as the probability of both is identical. Then, you are only performing “*number of lines*”×“*word per line*”×“*word per line*” operations, in other words, roughly 16,000 operations in your case.

The following method combines all words of a line, only keeping one of the “a_b”/“b_a” combination, and eliminates duplicates so each combination can count as a line.

```
static Stream<String> allCombinations(String line) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    return Arrays.stream(words)
        .flatMap(word1 ->
            Arrays.stream(words)
                  .filter(words2 -> word1.compareTo(words2)<0)
                  .map(word2 -> word1+'_'+word2))
        .distinct();
}
```

This method can be use like

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/reviews-preprocessing.txt"));
double ratio = 1.0/lines.size();
Map<String, Double> pij = lines.stream()
        .flatMap(line -> allCombinations(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                       Collectors.summingDouble(x->ratio)));
```

It ran through my copy of “War and Peace” within a few seconds, without needing any attempt to do parallel processing. Not much surprising, “and_the” was the combination with the highest probability.

You may consider changing the line

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

to

```
String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
```

to generalize the code to work with different input, handling multiple spaces or other punctuation characters and ignoring the case.

Comment: there is an opinion that the actual book name should have been `war and humanity(planet, light, earth)` etc - as in a word that does NOT define `!= war && == peace`. originally it was written as `мiръ` (which is `!= peace`). This now is seen as either a typo in the first printed book or a word that is != peace, still the name will probably leave on as "war and peace" anyway

Comment: @Eugene: I wasn’t aware that there were two distinct words for world and peace before the revolution; I only knew the “мир” meaning both. But anyway, your assumption is right, we will continue using the well-known name to be sure that the reader also knows what we’re talking about…